# find minimum value in a column based on condition in an another column of a dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I want to select the minimum value of a column range based on another column condition

```
   0      1      2      3      4   Capacity   Fixed Cost

  80.0  270.0  250.0  160.0  180.0   NaN        NaN

  4.0    5.0    6.0    8.0   10.0    500.0     1000.0

  6.0    4.0    3.0    5.0    8.0    500.0     1000.0

  9.0    7.0    4.0    3.0    4.0    500.0     1000.0
```

I get the minimum value of the column with  dv.loc[1:, i].min()
but i want to exclude rows where the capacity is 0

Comment: Can you ad expected ouput from sample data? Why is used `dv.loc[1:, i].min()` ? What is `i` ? there is some loop?

Comment: I use a loop for iterate over the data frame, i will be the column,I use 1: to skip the first row of the column
I want to skip the row if the capacity it's 0

Answer (score 1):

IIUC use:

```
df[df['Capacity'].ne(0)].min()
```

Comment: I use a loop for iterate over the data frame, i will be the column,I use 1: to skip the first row of the column I want to skip the row if the capacity it's 0